# How to put PyQt widgets inside an array

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to put widgets inside an array, for example I need in my array some `QProgressBar`. (I got a `QProgressBar` class).

And after, I'm gonna need these `QProgressBar` to modify their values and so on using my array. For example `array[2].show()` isn't even working.

```
DataBar = []
BarrePositionX = 1000
BarrePositionY= 590
for NombreDeShaker in range(0, nb_shaker):
    for NbDeBar in range(0, 4):
        DataBar.append(BarPourcentage(self))
        DataBar.move(BarrePositionX, BarrePositionY)
        DataBar.show()
        BarrePositionY += 22
    BarrePositionY=590
    BarrePositionX += 150
```

If I use `move()` and `show()` for only `DataBar[0]`, it's working but only for 0 (and 1,2,3.. doesn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get your list `DataBar` and your widget mixed up.

In your loop, create a widget, apply all changes that you need (`move` and `show`). Then, add it to your list:

```
        DataBar = []
        BarrePositionX = 1000
        BarrePositionY= 590
        for NombreDeShaker in range(0, nb_shaker):
            for NbDeBar in range(0, 4):
                bar = BarPourcentage(self)
                bar.move(BarrePositionX, BarrePositionY)
                DataBar.append(bar)
                BarrePositionY += 22
            BarrePositionY=590
            BarrePositionX += 150
```